# 'font-family: Symbol' and Windows-1252

Tags: html, css, encoding, character-encoding, fonts

I have a bunch of HTML documents that contain some simple text in `Windows-1252` encoding, but throughout the text there are numerous appearances of `span` elements with `font-family: Symbol`.

For example:

```
<span style='font-family:Symbol'>Ñ</span>
```

Which appears as the greek delta - Δ in the browser.

Google told me that using the `Symbol` font might show different results on different systems, as it's not actually a well defined font.
**Is this really true? Is it "unsafe" to use the `Symbol` font?**

If so, is there any way to reliably convert (on my own system) such symbols in the `Symbol` font to their `Windows-1252` counterparts?

Comment: Windows-1252 doesn't have many symbols at all. Is using UTF-8 an option? Alternatively you can use html references, ie `&#916;` for the delta character.. just remove the font family.

Comment: @Esailija if converting Windows-1252 to UTF-8 is safe then I guess its possible.

Comment: But you are not converting from Windows-1252 to UTF-8. If you want a delta character, you need to write a delta character. If you just convert from Windows-1252 to UTF-8, you will just get `Ñ` instead and continue to rely on the font. But you can write the text you need and save as UTF-8, and you will literally end up with the delta character because UTF-8 can encode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been always unsafe to rely on having certain font installed on all the computers/smartphones/gadgets that visit your site. There're some font embedding techniques that work reasonably well in some modern browsers but you'd need to repack the Symbol font and I doubt the copyright owner allows you to do it.

Of course, most characters in the Symbol font are not in the Windows-1252 encoding but that should not be an issue. You can use the [following map](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/CM/AdobeSym.html) to obtain the appropriate HTML entities. However, you'll have to write a script or program using a programming language (HTML is just a markup language).

Comment: Well, I've ended up parsing that map you linked and using `HtmlAgilityPack` to apply it to all my files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the greek letter you see is just the appearance, the actual letter is something completely different.

I can think of two ways to convert it:
1. Write a script (in your language of choice) that converts each letter to it's Greek counterpart. (Ñ => Δ)
2. Take a screenshot of the document/page and use an OCR-program to convert it to Greek text.

Answer (score 0):

When using `font-family`, if neither of the listed font faces are found on the client, that is  without the webfont embeds, may result in changing to default font of client hence a different font replacement for what you'd show to your users.

You may want to use UTF-8 encoding and put the delta (Δ) sign in your HTML content, or use webfont embeds to provide an option, "use the font I want from this".